# What is the BLAB_MEM environment variable in Windows?

Tags: windows-vista, environment-variables

On my Windows Vista system I see an environment variable called BLAB_MEM, with the value 
"-Xms128M -Xmx512M".  This variable name is shown under both the system and user variables. That value (-Xms128M -Xmx512M) looks like a set of arguments to a command line invocation of Java, but where did the BLAB_MEM variable name come from??

I've googled for BLAB_MEM but nothing relevant comes up, so I am turning to the super-duper SuperUser community.

Here are some more details in case they might be relevant:
The most recent software I've installed is the QSTK package for python, in connection with a MOOC from Georgia Tech through Coursera.  There is nothing in the course forums about this environment variable.

My system is an HP laptop running Windows Vista Home Premium, service pack 2, with Chrome and McAfee  installed. Vista, Chrome and McAfee are all up to date.